# PHP foreach + continue not working on multidimensional array

Tags: php, foreach

I'm looking for a way to filter the array on a foreach loop based on two parameters..

I have in my output the following array:

```
[
  {
    "entry_id": "1",
    "title": "something",
    "grades": [
      "3",
      "4",
      "5",
      "6"
    ],
    "subject": [
      "science"
    ]
  },
  {
    "entry_id": "2",
    "title": "something else",
    "grades": [
      "7",
      "8",
      "9",
      "10"
    ],
    "subject": [
      "math"
    ]
  },
]
```

I'm trying to return only entry_id 2 using `foreach` + `break`, from what I've read it seems like this should work..

```
$subject = 'math';
$grade = '10';

foreach ( $results as $key => &$result ) {
        if($subject && !in_array($subject, $result['subject'])){
            break;
        }
        if($grade && !in_array($grade, $result['grades'])){
            break;
        }
}
```

But it's returning all entries..

Comment: You don't have a `return` statement, how is it returning anything?

Comment: `continue` means to skip the rest of the loop body, and go to the next iteration of the loop. But you don't have anything in the loop body, so it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: If you want to stop the loop, use `break`.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar, I've updated it to !in_array;  So the loop should stop if there is a variable and it's in array, but it's still not working...

Comment: Your loop stops when the variable is *not* in the array.

Comment: But - either way it still returns all entries if I have $subject = 'math' or if I have $subject = ' '

Comment: Your code doesn't return anything, so how can it return all entries?

Comment: You're not removing anything from the array, so if you do `return $results;`, it will be unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to add the current entry to a new array when it passes any of the tests. So change the `!in_array()` test to `in_array()`, and add to the result inside that `if` block.

```
$realresults = array();
foreach ( $results as $key => &$result ) {
    if($subject && in_array($subject, $result['subject'])){
        $realresults[] = $result;
    } elseif($grade && in_array($grade, $result['grades'])){
        $realresults[] = $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep - tried this, but it only works for the first parameter, if you try to filter the results further by the second (grade in this case) it doesn't work :-/

Comment: It only keeps results that match both parameters. Do you want to keep results that match either criteria?

Comment: Yes, by either or criteria... but I think they would be preferential too right?  Like if I filtered by subject first it might have not as many results as if I filtered the other way around like by grade first.  So my preference is subject first then grade...

Comment: You need to change the sense of the test. If it matches a test, add it to the result. The above code goes through all the tests, skipping if it fails, and then adds to the result if it didn't fail any test.

Comment: If it should be either criteria, why would it be preferential?

Answer (score 0):

After searching some more seems like unset + array_values will do what I need:

```
foreach ( $results as $key => &$result ) {
    if($subject && !in_array($subject, $result['subject'])){
        unset($results[$key]);
        $results = array_values($results);
    }
    if($grade && !in_array($grade, $result['grades'])){
        unset($results[$key]);
        $results = array_values($results);
    }
}
```